# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup MasterIP on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I am trying to start Kubernetes with 'kubectl apply -f redis.yaml' and I am getting

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup MasterIP on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
```

Before, I was receiving

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

This error. I was searching for the solution and someone said trying to use this command

```
export KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://MasterIP:8080
```

After that, I am receiving the error above? How can I fix this?

```
kubectl cluster-info

Kubernetes master is running at 192.168.219.107:6443 
KubeDNS is running at 192.168.219.107:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/
```

my ./kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 
    server: https://****:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 
    client-key-data:
```

Comment: How did setup cluster?  You have a valid `kubeconfig` file ?Can you add output of `kubectl cluster-info`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://MasterIP:8080` is not correct because the port should be `6443` and protocol should be `https` for external connection coming to Kubernetes API Server.

```
export KUBERNETES_MASTER=https://MasterIP:6443`
```

You seem to have a valid `kubeconfig` file and so you really don't need to export `KUBERNETES_MASTER` environment variable.

Make sure that the file is located at `.kube/config` path in your `home` directory. otherwise point `KUBECONFIG` environment variable to the path where the `kubeconfig` file is located.

Answer (score -3):

You should use

```
kubectl apply -f
```

See [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml) for reference

Comment: This answer is totally wrong. 1) missing a yaml file 2) if you do not have a connection to the control plane, you cannot apply any manifest